# Performance optimization by removing items from WinForms ListView

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, listview

I have a ListView which shows incoming messages from another application. I'll receive these messages over a long period of time, so I can't hold them all in the ListView, at some point the memory would be full. Furthermore, I receive many items per second and my whole application should have a good performance.

Currently my ListView runs in virtual mode. To reduce the required memory I remove the item at index 0 from my virtual list if the max count of items is reached.

My problem at this point is that the time needed by the remove is very high. Is there any way to optimize this?

Here is some of my code to clarify what I do:

```
private uint maxItems = 10000;
private List<ListViewItem> virtualList = new List<ListViewItem>();
private bool autoScroll = true;

public void AddLine(ListViewItem newLine)
{    
    BeginUpdate();

    virtualList.Add(newLine);

    if (virtualList.Count >= maxItems)
    {
        virtualList.RemoveAt(0);
    }
    else
    {
        this.VirtualListSize = virtualList.Count;
    }

    if (autoScroll)
    {
        this.TopItem = Items[Items.Count - 1];
    }
    else
    {
        if (virtualList.Count == maxItems - 1)
        {
            this.TopItem = Items[this.TopItem.Index - 1];
        }
    }

    EndUpdate();
}

private void ListView_RetrieveVirtualItem(object sender, RetrieveVirtualItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.Item = virtualList[e.ItemIndex];
}
```

Comment: winforms is innefficient by design, but you could improve it by moving your List items "reception" to a separate thread and then dispatching calls to update the UI to the UI thread, thus, the slow winforms UI would not get in the way of your application processing the incoming messages. If you want a definitive solution, drop winforms and use any of current (< 10 years old), XAML-based technologies, which are orders of magnitude faster than winforms, and have built-in UI virtualization.

Comment: His question isn't really about Winforms. It's "Why is deleting the first element of a List (data structure) slow." The answer to that lies in how that collection class is implemented and allocates memory. Instead of using a list, you want to use a ring-buffer or similar data structure, where you overwrite the earlier items with newer items.

Comment: Yes but how can I use my listview to show my data stored in the ring-buffer? However, I'm using wpf for the performance relevant parts of my application now. But thank you for the comment!